# Why is adding DoubleStructs slower than adding doubles by a much bigger ratio than the long equivalent?

Tags: c#, performance, .net-core, x86-64, benchmarking

### Hypothesis

A `readonly struct` containing a single primitive should be more or less as fast for any simple operation as the primitive itself.

### Tests

All the tests below are running .NET Core 2.2 on Windows 7 x64, code optimised. I also get similar results when testing on .NET 4.7.2.

#### Test: Longs

Testing this premise with the `long` type, it seems that this holds:

```
// =============== SETUP ===================

public readonly struct LongStruct
{
    public readonly long Primitive;

    public LongStruct(long value) => Primitive = value;

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static LongStruct Add(in LongStruct lhs, in LongStruct rhs)
        => new LongStruct(lhs.Primitive + rhs.Primitive);
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public static long LongAdd(long lhs, long rhs) => lhs + rhs;

// =============== TESTS ===================

public static void TestLong(long a, long b, out long result)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    for (var i = 1000000000; i > 0; --i)
    {
        a = LongAdd(a, b);
    }

    sw.Stop();

    result = a;

    return sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
}

public static void TestLongStruct(LongStruct a, LongStruct b, out LongStruct result)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    for (var i = 1000000000; i > 0; --i)
    {
        a = LongStruct.Add(a, b);
    }

    sw.Stop();

    result = a;

    return sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
}

// ============= TEST LOOP =================

public static void RunTests()
{
    var longStruct = new LongStruct(1);

    var count = 0;
    var longTime = 0L;
    var longStructTime = 0L;

    while (true)
    {
        count++;
        Console.WriteLine("Test #" + count);

        longTime += TestLong(1, 1, out var longResult);
        var longMean = longTime / count;
        Console.WriteLine($"Long: value={longResult}, Mean Time elapsed: {longMean} ms");

        longStructTime += TestLongStruct(longStruct, longStruct, out var longStructResult);
        var longStructMean = longStructTime / count;
        Console.WriteLine($"LongStruct: value={longStructResult.Primitive}, Mean Time elapsed: {longStructMean} ms");

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

*`LongAdd` is used so the test loops match - each loop calls out to a method which does some adding, rather than inlining for the primitive case*

On my machine, the two times have settled down to within 2% of each other, close enough that I'm convinced they've been optimised to pretty much the same code.

The difference in IL is fairly small:

- the test loop code is the same with the exception of which method gets called (`LongAdd` vs `LongStruct.Add`).
- `LongStruct.Add` has a few extra instructions:

  - A pair of `ldfld` instructions to load `Primitive` from the struct
  - A `newobj` instruction to pack the new `long` back into a `LongStruct`

So either the jitter is optimising away these instructions, or they're basically free.

#### Test: Doubles

If I take the code above and replace every `long` with a `double`, I'd expect the same sort of result (slower in absolute terms, as the add instruction will be slightly slower, but both by the same margin).

What I actually see is that the `DoubleStruct` version is about 4.8 times (i.e. 480%) slower than the `double` version.

The IL is identical to the `long` case (other than swapping `int64` and `LongStruct` for `float64` and `DoubleStruct`), but somehow the runtime is doing a load of extra work for the `DoubleStruct` case that isn't present in the `LongStruct` case or the `double` case.

#### Test: Other Types

Testing a few other primitive types, I see that `float` (465%) behaves the same way as `double`, and `short` and `int` behave the same way as `long`, so it seems it's something about floating point that is causing some optimisation not to be taken.

### Question

Why are `DoubleStruct` and `FloatStruct` so much slower than `double` and `float`, where the `long`, `int` and `short` equivalents suffer no such slowdown?

Comment: As an aside, use BenchmarkDotNet

Comment: Have you looked at the x86 instructions that actually run, to see what the JIT did?  With strict FP, you should just bottleneck on FP-add latency, unless the compiler auto-vectorizes one way but not the other.  (e.g. a vector of accumulators that each get 1/4 of the total).  Obviously it's a huge missed optimization that the compiler didn't replace both loops with `return a + b*1000000000;`.

Comment: Maybe JIT hoisted or sunk the work out of one loop but *did* keep the loop?  That would explain a factor of 4 difference on a Skylake CPU: 1/clock empty loop throughput vs.  4-cycle latency `addsd` or `addss`.  That doesn't quite explain 465% or 480% though.  I think you're controlling for warm-up effects like CPU frequency and initial JIT by alternating them in a loop.

Comment: The issue is not that the double test is too slow, it is that the long test is too fast.  The tool that the answerers used is not good enough to demonstrate why, it is not capable of showing the code-inlining and dead-code-elimination strategies that the jitter optimizer uses to make code faster.  It is the latter that trips you up, the Add() call has no observable side-effects in this test so can be eliminated.  All that you measure is the cost of the for-loop.  You have to rewrite the test so this can't happen, like adding the return values and returning it as the method result.

Comment: @HansPassant The setup in the answers may not use the result of the additions, but the setup in the question does return the sum as an `out` parameter, (and sends it to `Console.WriteLine` in the end) and still shows a significant speed difference.

Comment: You didn't post the code that had the perf problem, I went by what the answerers used.  Details are important.

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't want to add a near-identical block of code - it seemed like extra noise to me. "If I take the code above and replace every long with a double ..." seemed clear enough.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't an answer on its own, but it's a bit of a more rigorous benchmark, on both x86 and x64, so hopefully it provides some more information to someone else who can explain this.

I tried to replicate this with BenchmarkDotNet. I also wanted to see what difference removing the `in` would do. I ran it separately as x86 and x64.

**x86 (LegacyJIT)**

```
|                 Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev |
|----------------------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|
|               TestLong | 257.9 ms | 2.099 ms | 1.964 ms |
|         TestLongStruct | 529.3 ms | 4.977 ms | 4.412 ms |
|   TestLongStructWithIn | 526.2 ms | 6.722 ms | 6.288 ms |
|             TestDouble | 256.7 ms | 1.466 ms | 1.300 ms |
|       TestDoubleStruct | 342.5 ms | 5.189 ms | 4.600 ms |
| TestDoubleStructWithIn | 338.7 ms | 3.808 ms | 3.376 ms |
```

**x64 (RyuJIT)**

```
|                 Method |       Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
|----------------------- |-----------:|----------:|----------:|
|               TestLong |   269.8 ms |  5.359 ms |  9.099 ms |
|         TestLongStruct |   266.2 ms |  6.706 ms |  8.236 ms |
|   TestLongStructWithIn |   270.4 ms |  4.150 ms |  3.465 ms |
|             TestDouble |   270.4 ms |  5.336 ms |  6.748 ms |
|       TestDoubleStruct | 1,250.9 ms | 24.702 ms | 25.367 ms |
| TestDoubleStructWithIn |   577.1 ms | 12.159 ms | 16.644 ms |
```

I can replicate this on x64 with RyuJIT, but not on x86 with LegacyJIT. This seems to be an artifact of RyuJIT managing the optimize the `long` case but not the `double` case - LegacyJIT doesn't mange to optimize either.

I've no idea why TestDoubleStruct is such an outlier on RyuJIT.

Code:

```
public readonly struct LongStruct
{
    public readonly long Primitive;

    public LongStruct(long value) => Primitive = value;

    public static LongStruct Add(LongStruct lhs, LongStruct rhs)
        => new LongStruct(lhs.Primitive + rhs.Primitive);
    public static LongStruct AddWithIn(in LongStruct lhs, in LongStruct rhs)
        => new LongStruct(lhs.Primitive + rhs.Primitive);
}

public readonly struct DoubleStruct
{
    public readonly double Primitive;

    public DoubleStruct(double value) => Primitive = value;

    public static DoubleStruct Add(DoubleStruct lhs, DoubleStruct rhs)
        => new DoubleStruct(lhs.Primitive + rhs.Primitive);
    public static DoubleStruct AddWithIn(in DoubleStruct lhs, in DoubleStruct rhs)
        => new DoubleStruct(lhs.Primitive + rhs.Primitive);
}


public class Benchmark
{
    [Benchmark]
    public void TestLong()
    {
        for (var i = 1000000000; i > 0; --i)
        {
            LongAdd(1, 2);
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void TestLongStruct()
    {
        var a = new LongStruct(1);
        var b = new LongStruct(2);

        for (var i = 1000000000; i > 0; --i)
        {
            LongStruct.Add(a, b);
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void TestLongStructWithIn()
    {
        var a = new LongStruct(1);
        var b = new LongStruct(2);

        for (var i = 1000000000; i > 0; --i)
        {
            LongStruct.AddWithIn(a, b);
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void TestDouble()
    {
        for (var i = 1000000000; i > 0; --i)
        {
            DoubleAdd(1, 2);
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void TestDoubleStruct()
    {
        var a = new DoubleStruct(1);
        var b = new DoubleStruct(2);

        for (var i = 1000000000; i > 0; --i)
        {
            DoubleStruct.Add(a, b);
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void TestDoubleStructWithIn()
    {
        var a = new DoubleStruct(1);
        var b = new DoubleStruct(2);

        for (var i = 1000000000; i > 0; --i)
        {
            DoubleStruct.AddWithIn(a, b);
        }
    }

    public static long LongAdd(long lhs, long rhs) => lhs + rhs;
    public static double DoubleAdd(double lhs, double rhs) => lhs + rhs;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<Benchmark>();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

---

For fun, here's the x64 assembly for both cases:

**Code**

```
using System;

public class C {
    public long AddLongs(long a, long b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    public LongStruct AddLongStructs(LongStruct a, LongStruct b) {
        return LongStruct.Add(a, b);
    }

    public LongStruct AddLongStructsWithIn(LongStruct a, LongStruct b) {
        return LongStruct.AddWithIn(a, b);
    }

    public double AddDoubles(double a, double b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    public DoubleStruct AddDoubleStructs(DoubleStruct a, DoubleStruct b) {
        return DoubleStruct.Add(a, b);
    }

    public DoubleStruct AddDoubleStructsWithIn(DoubleStruct a, DoubleStruct b) {
        return DoubleStruct.AddWithIn(a, b);
    }
}

public readonly struct LongStruct
{
    public readonly long Primitive;

    public LongStruct(long value) => Primitive = value;

    public static LongStruct Add(LongStruct lhs, LongStruct rhs)
        => new LongStruct(lhs.Primitive + rhs.Primitive);
    public static LongStruct AddWithIn(in LongStruct lhs, in LongStruct rhs)
        => new LongStruct(lhs.Primitive + rhs.Primitive);
}   

public readonly struct DoubleStruct
{
    public readonly double Primitive;

    public DoubleStruct(double value) => Primitive = value;

    public static DoubleStruct Add(DoubleStruct lhs, DoubleStruct rhs)
        => new DoubleStruct(lhs.Primitive + rhs.Primitive);
    public static DoubleStruct AddWithIn(in DoubleStruct lhs, in DoubleStruct rhs)
        => new DoubleStruct(lhs.Primitive + rhs.Primitive);
}
```

**x86 Assembly**

```
C.AddLongs(Int64, Int64)
    L0000: mov eax, [esp+0xc]
    L0004: mov edx, [esp+0x10]
    L0008: add eax, [esp+0x4]
    L000c: adc edx, [esp+0x8]
    L0010: ret 0x10

C.AddLongStructs(LongStruct, LongStruct)
    L0000: push esi
    L0001: mov eax, [esp+0x10]
    L0005: mov esi, [esp+0x14]
    L0009: add eax, [esp+0x8]
    L000d: adc esi, [esp+0xc]
    L0011: mov [edx], eax
    L0013: mov [edx+0x4], esi
    L0016: pop esi
    L0017: ret 0x10

C.AddLongStructsWithIn(LongStruct, LongStruct)
    L0000: push esi
    L0001: mov eax, [esp+0x10]
    L0005: mov esi, [esp+0x14]
    L0009: add eax, [esp+0x8]
    L000d: adc esi, [esp+0xc]
    L0011: mov [edx], eax
    L0013: mov [edx+0x4], esi
    L0016: pop esi
    L0017: ret 0x10

C.AddDoubles(Double, Double)
    L0000: fld qword [esp+0xc]
    L0004: fadd qword [esp+0x4]
    L0008: ret 0x10

C.AddDoubleStructs(DoubleStruct, DoubleStruct)
    L0000: fld qword [esp+0xc]
    L0004: fld qword [esp+0x4]
    L0008: faddp st1, st0
    L000a: fstp qword [edx]
    L000c: ret 0x10

C.AddDoubleStructsWithIn(DoubleStruct, DoubleStruct)
    L0000: fld qword [esp+0xc]
    L0004: fadd qword [esp+0x4]
    L0008: fstp qword [edx]
    L000a: ret 0x10
```

**x64 Assembly**

```
C..ctor()
    L0000: ret

C.AddLongs(Int64, Int64)
    L0000: lea rax, [rdx+r8]
    L0004: ret

C.AddLongStructs(LongStruct, LongStruct)
    L0000: lea rax, [rdx+r8]
    L0004: ret

C.AddLongStructsWithIn(LongStruct, LongStruct)
    L0000: lea rax, [rdx+r8]
    L0004: ret

C.AddDoubles(Double, Double)
    L0000: vzeroupper
    L0003: vmovaps xmm0, xmm1
    L0008: vaddsd xmm0, xmm0, xmm2
    L000d: ret

C.AddDoubleStructs(DoubleStruct, DoubleStruct)
    L0000: sub rsp, 0x18
    L0004: vzeroupper
    L0007: mov [rsp+0x28], rdx
    L000c: mov [rsp+0x30], r8
    L0011: mov rax, [rsp+0x28]
    L0016: mov [rsp+0x10], rax
    L001b: mov rax, [rsp+0x30]
    L0020: mov [rsp+0x8], rax
    L0025: vmovsd xmm0, qword [rsp+0x10]
    L002c: vaddsd xmm0, xmm0, [rsp+0x8]
    L0033: vmovsd [rsp], xmm0
    L0039: mov rax, [rsp]
    L003d: add rsp, 0x18
    L0041: ret

C.AddDoubleStructsWithIn(DoubleStruct, DoubleStruct)
    L0000: push rax
    L0001: vzeroupper
    L0004: mov [rsp+0x18], rdx
    L0009: mov [rsp+0x20], r8
    L000e: vmovsd xmm0, qword [rsp+0x18]
    L0015: vaddsd xmm0, xmm0, [rsp+0x20]
    L001c: vmovsd [rsp], xmm0
    L0022: mov rax, [rsp]
    L0026: add rsp, 0x8
    L002a: ret
```

[SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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=)

---

If you add in the loops:

**Code**

```
public class C {
    public void AddLongs(long a, long b) {
        for (var i = 1000000000; i > 0; --i) {
            long c = a + b;
        }
    }

    public void AddLongStructs(LongStruct a, LongStruct b) {
        for (var i = 1000000000; i > 0; --i) {
            a = LongStruct.Add(a, b);
        }
    }

    public void AddLongStructsWithIn(LongStruct a, LongStruct b) {
        for (var i = 1000000000; i > 0; --i) {
            a = LongStruct.AddWithIn(a, b);
        }
    }

    public void AddDoubles(double a, double b) {
        for (var i = 1000000000; i > 0; --i) {
            a = a + b;
        }
    }

    public void AddDoubleStructs(DoubleStruct a, DoubleStruct b) {
        for (var i = 1000000000; i > 0; --i) {
            a = DoubleStruct.Add(a, b);
        }
    }

    public void AddDoubleStructsWithIn(DoubleStruct a, DoubleStruct b) {
        for (var i = 1000000000; i > 0; --i) {
            a = DoubleStruct.AddWithIn(a, b);
        }
    }
}

public readonly struct LongStruct
{
    public readonly long Primitive;

    public LongStruct(long value) => Primitive = value;

    public static LongStruct Add(LongStruct lhs, LongStruct rhs)
        => new LongStruct(lhs.Primitive + rhs.Primitive);
    public static LongStruct AddWithIn(in LongStruct lhs, in LongStruct rhs)
        => new LongStruct(lhs.Primitive + rhs.Primitive);
}   

public readonly struct DoubleStruct
{
    public readonly double Primitive;

    public DoubleStruct(double value) => Primitive = value;

    public static DoubleStruct Add(DoubleStruct lhs, DoubleStruct rhs)
        => new DoubleStruct(lhs.Primitive + rhs.Primitive);
    public static DoubleStruct AddWithIn(in DoubleStruct lhs, in DoubleStruct rhs)
        => new DoubleStruct(lhs.Primitive + rhs.Primitive);
}
```

**x86**

```
C.AddLongs(Int64, Int64)
    L0000: push ebp
    L0001: mov ebp, esp
    L0003: mov eax, 0x3b9aca00
    L0008: dec eax
    L0009: test eax, eax
    L000b: jg L0008
    L000d: pop ebp
    L000e: ret 0x10

C.AddLongStructs(LongStruct, LongStruct)
    L0000: push ebp
    L0001: mov ebp, esp
    L0003: push esi
    L0004: mov esi, 0x3b9aca00
    L0009: mov eax, [ebp+0x10]
    L000c: mov edx, [ebp+0x14]
    L000f: add eax, [ebp+0x8]
    L0012: adc edx, [ebp+0xc]
    L0015: mov [ebp+0x10], eax
    L0018: mov [ebp+0x14], edx
    L001b: dec esi
    L001c: test esi, esi
    L001e: jg L0009
    L0020: pop esi
    L0021: pop ebp
    L0022: ret 0x10

C.AddLongStructsWithIn(LongStruct, LongStruct)
    L0000: push ebp
    L0001: mov ebp, esp
    L0003: push esi
    L0004: mov esi, 0x3b9aca00
    L0009: mov eax, [ebp+0x10]
    L000c: mov edx, [ebp+0x14]
    L000f: add eax, [ebp+0x8]
    L0012: adc edx, [ebp+0xc]
    L0015: mov [ebp+0x10], eax
    L0018: mov [ebp+0x14], edx
    L001b: dec esi
    L001c: test esi, esi
    L001e: jg L0009
    L0020: pop esi
    L0021: pop ebp
    L0022: ret 0x10

C.AddDoubles(Double, Double)
    L0000: push ebp
    L0001: mov ebp, esp
    L0003: mov eax, 0x3b9aca00
    L0008: dec eax
    L0009: test eax, eax
    L000b: jg L0008
    L000d: pop ebp
    L000e: ret 0x10

C.AddDoubleStructs(DoubleStruct, DoubleStruct)
    L0000: push ebp
    L0001: mov ebp, esp
    L0003: mov eax, 0x3b9aca00
    L0008: fld qword [ebp+0x10]
    L000b: fld qword [ebp+0x8]
    L000e: faddp st1, st0
    L0010: fstp qword [ebp+0x10]
    L0013: dec eax
    L0014: test eax, eax
    L0016: jg L0008
    L0018: pop ebp
    L0019: ret 0x10

C.AddDoubleStructsWithIn(DoubleStruct, DoubleStruct)
    L0000: push ebp
    L0001: mov ebp, esp
    L0003: mov eax, 0x3b9aca00
    L0008: fld qword [ebp+0x10]
    L000b: fadd qword [ebp+0x8]
    L000e: fstp qword [ebp+0x10]
    L0011: dec eax
    L0012: test eax, eax
    L0014: jg L0008
    L0016: pop ebp
    L0017: ret 0x10
```

**x64**

```
C.AddLongs(Int64, Int64)
    L0000: mov eax, 0x3b9aca00
    L0005: dec eax
    L0007: test eax, eax
    L0009: jg L0005
    L000b: ret

C.AddLongStructs(LongStruct, LongStruct)
    L0000: mov eax, 0x3b9aca00
    L0005: add rdx, r8
    L0008: dec eax
    L000a: test eax, eax
    L000c: jg L0005
    L000e: ret

C.AddLongStructsWithIn(LongStruct, LongStruct)
    L0000: mov eax, 0x3b9aca00
    L0005: add rdx, r8
    L0008: dec eax
    L000a: test eax, eax
    L000c: jg L0005
    L000e: ret

C.AddDoubles(Double, Double)
    L0000: vzeroupper
    L0003: mov eax, 0x3b9aca00
    L0008: vaddsd xmm1, xmm1, xmm2
    L000d: dec eax
    L000f: test eax, eax
    L0011: jg L0008
    L0013: ret

C.AddDoubleStructs(DoubleStruct, DoubleStruct)
    L0000: sub rsp, 0x18
    L0004: vzeroupper
    L0007: mov [rsp+0x28], rdx
    L000c: mov [rsp+0x30], r8
    L0011: mov eax, 0x3b9aca00
    L0016: mov rdx, [rsp+0x28]
    L001b: mov [rsp+0x10], rdx
    L0020: mov rdx, [rsp+0x30]
    L0025: mov [rsp+0x8], rdx
    L002a: vmovsd xmm0, qword [rsp+0x10]
    L0031: vaddsd xmm0, xmm0, [rsp+0x8]
    L0038: vmovsd [rsp], xmm0
    L003e: mov rdx, [rsp]
    L0042: mov [rsp+0x28], rdx
    L0047: dec eax
    L0049: test eax, eax
    L004b: jg L0016
    L004d: add rsp, 0x18
    L0051: ret

C.AddDoubleStructsWithIn(DoubleStruct, DoubleStruct)
    L0000: push rax
    L0001: vzeroupper
    L0004: mov [rsp+0x18], rdx
    L0009: mov [rsp+0x20], r8
    L000e: mov eax, 0x3b9aca00
    L0013: vmovsd xmm0, qword [rsp+0x20]
    L001a: vmovaps xmm1, xmm0
    L001f: vaddsd xmm1, xmm1, [rsp+0x18]
    L0026: vmovsd [rsp], xmm1
    L002c: mov rdx, [rsp]
    L0030: mov [rsp+0x18], rdx
    L0035: dec eax
    L0037: test eax, eax
    L0039: jg L001a
    L003b: add rsp, 0x8
    L003f: ret
```

[SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

I'm not familiar enough with assembly to explain what exactly it's doing, but it's clear that more work is going on in `AddDoubleStructs` than in `AddLongStructs`.

Comment: You've got your `in` s in the wrong place on `LongStruct`

Comment: D'oh. I'll correct and re-run, thanks. It didn't seem to make much difference anyway.

Comment: It didn't. You could just swap the names on the results :)

Comment: @canton7: Integer add inside an empty loop wouldn't slow it down any; it should still run at 1 cycle / iteration.  But in 32-bit mode, where an int64 takes an `add/adc` chain of two 32-bit halves, the loop carried dependency chain is twice as long and becomes a bottleneck.  So your 32-bit results are interesting, and loop consistent with that JIT optimizing `TestLong` out of the loop into a multiply, but not the other `long` versions.  IDK how to explain the `340 ms` for `TestDoubleStruct` and `TestDoubleStruct in`; maybe the ~250ms case wasn't 1 cycle / iter.

Comment: @canton7: Your asm dump left out the definition for `TestLong` after inlining `LongStruct.Add`.  The stand-alone definitions have *huge* overhead compared to 1 asm instruction.  Also, are you sure that's even optimized asm?  It looks like some redundant spill/reload in `C.AddDoubleStructs`.  And some insane bouncing of data from integer to XMM regs and back.  I guess the calling convention passes a struct containing `double` in integer regs!!  But the final store/reload / store looks like a missed optimization.

Comment: @PeterCordes I've tweaked the assembly output a bit, take another look.

Comment: Ok, that's the optimized asm for stand-alone definitions of these functions.  Store/reload instead of `movq xmm0, r8` is a missed optimization (but the insanity of that transfer in the first place is required by the calling convention).  You still left out the loops where these inline (or not), so we still have zero idea what's actually happening in the loops.

Comment: On x64, manually inlining `DoubleStruct.Add` seems to perform better than calling the struct method, but still slower than the `double` version by a factor of 3 (on my machine). As you'd expect, inlining `LongStruct.Add` is as performant as the other cases.

Comment: @PeterCordes added in the loops, although to my untrained eye it looks comparable to the cases without loops

Comment: Heh, braindead JIT puts an extra `test eax,eax` after `dec eax` already set the flags.  `dec` / `jge` would be equivalent for `do{ } while(--i >0);`, especially because the starting value is a compile-time constant that's known positive.

Comment: Anyway, yes the integer loops do the work inside the loop, and just run at 1 iter / clock anyway because all the pass/return overhead optimizes away.  And the plain `double` optimizes down to just one FP add.  But the struct is still bouncing the data between integer and FP registers!!  This is the part I expected *not* to be the same, so it's highly surprising that so little of that optimized away.  There's zero reason to keep copying a `double` into integer registers (and storing/reloading to memory) after optimizing away the function call.  So the dep chain include FP add + 2x store/reload.

Comment: @PeterCordes if you want to take my dissassembly and write up an answer that the OP can accept, feel free. I don't have the assembly knowledge to write something that can be accepted as the answer.

Comment: Your timing numbers don't match the release-mode asm from SharpLab.  I don't see how `TestDoubleStructWithIn` can be slower than an integer loop (1/clock) while only being 2x slower, not 3 or 4.  Did you do your timing run in a Debug build?  That would limit all the loops to at best 1 iter per ~6 cycles from keeping the loop counter in memory, with only the very slow FP loops having a bottleneck worse than that.

Comment: Nope, release with no debugger. I'll re-run when I get the chance.

Comment: What CPU model are you testing on?  (Also what JIT version?  Is it the same as the version you selected on SharpLab?)  Anyway, it's possible to get the actual asm from your own desktop, so you could see exactly what your benchmark is running.  Easiest way might be to start the benchmark and then interrupt it with a debugger.  (Release build, but still attach a debugger to it).  99.99% of the time it will be inside the main loop when you do that.

Comment: Benchmark was run on an i7-8650U. It's entirely possible that it's a different JIT version to SharpLab, so don't be too surprised if there are small differences. I'm off my lunchbreak now, so I'll dig into it again tomorrow if I have time.

Comment: A factor of 4x difference is *not* small. The integer loops on SharpLab easily run at 1 clock/iter on any modern x86 (or 2c if it splits across a cache-line boundary on a CPU without a loop buffer, or a disabled loop buffer like SKL/KBL with updated microcode).  On your CoffeeLake, `[v]addsd` has 4 cycle latency so the primitive double loop will run at 4 cycles / iteration.  But your numbers show it with the same perf as Long, not 4x slower.   At max turbo = 4.20GHz, we should expect ~238 ms for that many iters, so your integer loops are running about 1 c / iter.

Comment: Was your CPU frequency varying wildly during testing of some functions?  A U-series CPU might not sustain max turbo even in a loop that doesn't activate any SIMD ALUs.  So that might explain the doublestruct being 5x slower instead of 4x?  Or maybe the integer loops ran at lower frequency without the bottleneck FP-add latency to keep the power consumption lower?

Answer (score 3):

See @canton7's answer for some timing results and x86 asm output that I based my conclusions on.  (I don't have Windows or a C# compiler).

Anomalies: **the "release" asm for the loops on SharpLab don't match @canton7's BenchmarkDotNet performance numbers for any Intel or AMD CPUs.  The asm shows `TestDouble` really does `a+=b` inside the loop, but the timing shows it running as fast as the 1/clock integer loop.**  (FP add latency is 3 to 5 cycles on all AMD K8/K10/Bulldozer-family/Ryzen, and Intel P6 through Skylake.)

Maybe that's only a first-pass optimization, and after running longer the JIT will optimize away the FP add entirely (since the value is not returned).  **So I think unfortunately we still don't really have the asm that's *actually* running, but we can see the kind of mess the JIT optimizer makes.**

I don't understand how `TestDoubleStructWithIn` could be slower than an integer loop but only twice as slow (not 3x), unless maybe the `long` loops aren't running at 1 iteration per clock.  With such high counts, startup overhead should be negligible.  A loop counter being kept in memory could explain it (imposing a ~6 cycle per iteration bottleneck on everything, hiding the latency of anything except the very slow FP versions.)  But @canton7 says they tested with a Release build.  But their [i7-8650U](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/124968/intel-core-i7-8650u-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-20-ghz.html) might not maintain max-turbo = 4.20 GHz for all the loops, due to power/thermal limits.  (all-core minimum sustained frequency = 1.90 GHz), so looking at time in seconds instead of cycles could be throwing us off for the loops without a bottleneck?  That still doesn't explain primitive double being the same speed as long; those must have been optimized away.

---

**It's reasonable to *expect* this class to inline and optimize away, the way you're using it**.  A good compiler would do that.  But a JIT has to compile quickly, so it isn't always good, and clearly in this case is not for `double`.

For the integer loops, 64-bit integer add on x86-64 has 1 cycle latency, and modern superscalar CPUs have enough throughput to run a loop containing an add at the same speed as an otherwise-empty loop that just counts down a counter.  So we can't tell from the timings whether the compiler did `a + b * 1000000000` outside the loop, (but still ran an empty loop), or what.

@canton7 used SharpLab to look at the JIT x86-64 asm for a stand-alone version of `AddDoubleStructs`, and for the loop that calls it.  [standalone and loops, x86-64, release mode](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgHgbALANALiAhgZwLYB8ACAGABJgRgG4BYAKHMwGZ8AmXZORAOwBNEAbAe2YFNcA3uVwj8NbswDmuAIKtWAGR6TkACgnTEMXBtzAAlIOGiTmAOy5EuANR7SZEwF9jIl2NxKpAZTgAnAK4AxnCy8p6SPgHBauGRQSFaHspxwXqGQg4mouZJ3n7xAHRyrKqJBvZObm7UuKxc/sAc/MUAIvWNvGp1DU2W2t0daUaZWfgWVrbAFaLOI7jVNG09vCkhre1Nq2pLHat9uDub+akGw6MiOYcrx3BF8qXa5W6zposb11Fr8ldbAOoAlnAABYASWYqh+N32kM+Qwy5zGB3eqzurABwLBDzS0xEs1mlBomHo3C4AAdkGdsoSoKFFMo1LpErpTvDzgAzLi+XCqABuiC5/1wAF5cARsOKJRKiLhBQA+XDYaUAWiV/3SbhMAEhdIFhZYbHYNTNnlU5jVMDTirEbjFklDEtbYSyjSIOVzefyZXqxZLJdK5Qrlar1XMtVYRY7CsUsU9Q8a5i9RAt8JawnbPsh0aDwZHUg70/E4S7cG7uXyBd7fX6vfLFbgVWrKaNNeHchEbqis5iyvocVlE7jTa8U7Srl13vsBr1nXHXZyy57BSKfVW6wG6w2QwiW3qJobZ7gB4eh1SR+tllsIcj7doYYWZwjSx6K8vV+L/bha0HG6zm6278EqIxr2xZHkeyYWqO14Zl24IAQkt7QfeW7svOz5eq+b4fl+9bBk2WQ7iK8GdoC2bAX2lQJuQ+JkDUvi8IgdTMBwACeDBQrmcDkL+7j0YxPCsToyi4AACr4/yoIC/w8rw9jJpx6jCXyHD+LwhhCvKYkSVJMl6spqlyWahIEBAbZ7NGnE6ECyDaJZvjWfoxYabgfAAO5mTc6jWQUWmSXA0n8LY9nID54l+QFIFGfgJkebCxSwao/zMLFhYcNZ2hJSlqTBY5B7OW5WVwF5IW+TpgW4MFoXaf5MmRY4mrkASFUMUxgmMLC8HccmfGtWxU78KVNWyY1UXwao/W4PpanCppYVlXpnAGSNw6EKZ8G0leF5QmlNlIltsI5U58oFWNO1VeFulBd5g0RX25oxet8WkZimXrTtGXJeth15cdvDuad11zUNBqVTdtX2I4QA==).

We can see that for primitive `long c = a + b` it optimized away the add entirely (but kept an empty countdown loop)!  If we use `a = a+b;` we get an actual `add` instruction, even though `a` isn't returned from the function.

```
loops.AddLongs(Int64, Int64)
    L0000: mov eax, 0x3b9aca00    # i = init
                                  # do {
                                  #   long c = a+b   optimized out
    L0005: dec eax                #   --i;
    L0007: test eax, eax
    L0009: jg L0005               # }while(i>0);

    L000b: ret
```

But the struct version has an actual `add` instruction, from `a = LongStruct.Add(a, b);`.  (We do get the same with `a = a+b;` with primitive `long`.)

```
loops.AddLongStructs(LongStruct a, LongStruct b)
    L0000: mov eax, 0x3b9aca00

    L0005: add rdx, r8            # a += b;  other insns are identical
    L0008: dec eax
    L000a: test eax, eax
    L000c: jg L0005

    L000e: ret
```

But if we change it to `LongStruct.Add(a, b);` (not assigning the result anywhere), we get `L0006: add rdx, r8`  outside the loop (hoisting a+b), and then `L0009: mov rcx, rdx` / `L000c: mov [rsp], rcx` inside the loop.  (register copy and then store to a dead scratch space, totally insane.)  In C# (unlike C / C++), writing `a+b;` on its own as a statement is an error, so we can't see if the primitive equivalent would still result in stupid wasted instructions.  `Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement`.

**I don't think we can blame any of these missed optimizations on the struct per-se**.  But even if you benchmark this with/without an `add` in the loop, it won't doesn't result in an actual slowdown in this loop on modern x86.  The empty loop hits the 1/clock loop throughput bottleneck with only 2 uops on the loop (`dec` and macro-fused `test/jg`), leaving room for 2 more uops with no slowdown as long as they don't introduce any bottleneck worse than 1/clock.  (https://agner.org/optimize/)  e.g. `imul edx, r8d` with 3 cycle latency would slow the loop down by a factor of 3.  The "4 uops" front-end throughput is assuming a recent Intel.  Bulldozer-family is narrower, Ryzen is 5-wide.

These are non-static member functions of a class (for no reason, but I didn't notice right away so not changing it now).  In the asm calling convention, the first arg (RCX) is a `this` pointer, and args 2 and 3 are the explicit args to the member function (RDX and R8).

The JIT code-gen puts an extra `test eax,eax` after `dec eax` which already sets FLAGS (other than CF which we don't test) according to `i - 1`.  The starting point is a positive compile time constant; any C compiler would have optimized this to `dec eax` / `jnz`.  I think `dec eax` / `jg` would also work, falling through when `dec` produced zero, because `1 > 1` is false.

---

## DoubleStruct vs. the calling convention

**The calling convention used by C# on x86-64 passes 8-byte structs in integer registers**, which sucks for a struct that contains a `double` (because it has to get bounced to XMM registers for `vaddsd` or other FP operations).  So there is an unavoidable downside for your struct for non-inline function calls.

```
### stand-alone versions of functions: not inlined into a loop

# with primitive double, args are passed in XMM regs
standalone.AddDoubles(Double, Double)
    L0000: vzeroupper
    L0003: vmovaps xmm0, xmm1              # stupid missed optimization defeating the purpose of AVX 3-operand instructions
    L0008: vaddsd xmm0, xmm0, xmm2         # vaddsd xmm0,  xmm1, xmm2  would do retval = a + b
    L000d: ret

# without `in`.  Significantly less bad with `in`, see the link.
standalone.AddDoubleStructs(DoubleStruct a, DoubleStruct b)
    L0000: sub rsp, 0x18             # reserve 24 bytes of stack space
    L0004: vzeroupper                # Weird to use this in a function that doesn't have any YMM vectors...

    L0007: mov [rsp+0x28], rdx       # spill args 2 (rdx=double a) and 3 (r8=double b) to the stack.
    L000c: mov [rsp+0x30], r8        # (first arg = rcx = unused this pointer)

    L0011: mov rax, [rsp+0x28]
    L0016: mov [rsp+0x10], rax       # copy a to another place on the stack!

    L001b: mov rax, [rsp+0x30]
    L0020: mov [rsp+0x8], rax        # copy b to another place on the stack!

    L0025: vmovsd xmm0, qword [rsp+0x10]
    L002c: vaddsd xmm0, xmm0, [rsp+0x8]   # add a and b in the SSE/AVX FPU
    L0033: vmovsd [rsp], xmm0             # store the result to yet another stack location

    L0039: mov rax, [rsp]                 # reload it into RAX, the return value
    L003d: add rsp, 0x18
    L0041: ret
```

This is totally batshit insane.  This *is* release-mode code-gen, but the compiler stores the structs to memory, then reloads+stores them *again* before actually loading them into the FPU.  (I'm guessing the int->int copy might be a constructor, but I have no idea.  I normally look at C/C++ compiler output which isn't usually this dumb in optimized builds).

**Using `in` on the function arg avoids that extra copy of each input to a 2nd stack location**, but it does still transfer them from integer to XMM with store/reload.

That's what gcc does for int->xmm with default tuning, but it's a missed optimization.  Agner Fog says (in his microarch guide) that AMD's optimization manual suggests store/reload when tuning for Bulldozer, but he found it's not faster even on AMD.  (Where ALU int->xmm has ~10 cycle latency, vs. 2 to 3 cycles on Intel or on Ryzen, with 1/clock throughput same as stores.)

A good implementation of this function (if we're stuck with the calling convention) would be `vmovq xmm0, rdx` / `vmovq xmm1, r8`, then vaddsd then `vmovq rax, xmm0` / `ret`.

---

### After inlining into a loop

Primitive `double` optimizes similarly to `long`:

- Primitive: `double c = a + b;` optimizes away completely
- `a  = a + b` (like @canton7 used) still does *not*, even though the result is still unused.  This will bottleneck on `vaddsd` latency (3 to 5 cycles depending on Bulldozer vs. Ryzen vs. Intel pre-Skylake vs. Skylake.)  But it does stay in registers.

```
loops.AddDoubles(Double, Double)
    L0000: vzeroupper
    L0003: mov eax, 0x3b9aca00
                                        # do {
    L0008: vaddsd xmm1, xmm1, xmm2        # a += b
    L000d: dec eax                        # --i
    L000f: test eax, eax
    L0011: jg L0008                     # }while(i>0);

    L0013: ret
```

---

#### Inlining the struct version

All that store/reload overhead should go away after inlining the function into the loop; that's a large part of the point of inlining.  **Well surprise, it *doesn't* optimize away.  2x store/reload is on the critical path of the loop-carried data-dependency chain (of FP adds)!!!  This is a huge missed optimization.**

Store/reload latency is about 5 or 6 cycles on modern Intel, slower than an FP add.  `a` is being loaded/stored on the way into XMM0, and then again on the way back out.

```
loops.AddDoubleStructs(DoubleStruct, DoubleStruct)
    L0000: sub rsp, 0x18
    L0004: vzeroupper
    L0007: mov [rsp+0x28], rdx      # spill function args: a
    L000c: mov [rsp+0x30], r8       # and b
    L0011: mov eax, 0x3b9aca00      # i= init

                                    # do {
    L0016: mov rdx, [rsp+0x28]
    L001b: mov [rsp+0x10], rdx        # tmp_a = copy a to another local
    L0020: mov rdx, [rsp+0x30]
    L0025: mov [rsp+0x8], rdx         # tmp_b = copy b

    L002a: vmovsd xmm0, qword [rsp+0x10] # tmp_a
    L0031: vaddsd xmm0, xmm0, [rsp+0x8]  # + tmp_b
    L0038: vmovsd [rsp], xmm0            # tmp_a = sum

    L003e: mov rdx, [rsp]
    L0042: mov [rsp+0x28], rdx         # a = copy tmp_a

    L0047: dec eax                   #  --i;
    L0049: test eax, eax
    L004b: jg L0016                # }while(i>0)

    L004d: add rsp, 0x18
    L0051: ret
```

---

The primitive `double` loop optimizes to a simple loop keeping everything in registers, no clever optimization that would violate strict FP.  i.e. no turning it into a multiply, or using multiple accumulators to hide FP add latency.  (But we know from the `long` version that the compiler wouldn't do anything better regardless.)   It does all the additions as one long dependency chain, so one `addsd` per 3 (Broadwell or earlier, Ryzen) or 4 cycles (Skylake).

Comment: A very thorough answer! I think for the primitive long add, it's optimized the addition away because you've assigned it to a variable that's never used - changing it to a = a + b brings the add back. And I think some of the random-looking copies are to do with C# taking defensive copies (although I haven't quite figured out how).

Comment: @PhilipC: Oh, thanks for pointing out that oddity in @canton7's code (which I copied).  IDK why they used `long c = a+b` instead of `a+=b`.  Well spotted. 
 But there's nothing for the compiler to be "defensive" about; it got those values in registers, not via a pointer.  The copy source and destination are both locals that no other function or thread could legally have a pointer to, so this is pure missed optimization.  (i.e. escape analysis can prove that no reference to them escapes the function if it's done *after* inlining.  Or even before, because the call is pass by value).

Comment: @PhilipC: updated my answer: you were right, the apparent missed optimization with `long` vs. LongStruct was just a source difference.  It goes away when you make things consistent.  Anyway, extra copying from missed optimizations still explains DoubleStruct being much slower in a loop.

Comment: I can think of a good reason for extra store/loads in each loop.  Floating point registers have much greater internal precision than 64 bits, and when you save it out to a 64 bit variable, you're throwing away that precision.  As long as everything is in a local double, maybe it's allowed to use the FP stack registers, but by introducing a struct, it's forced to shrink it back down to a 64 bit value.  As an analogy, imagine you had a struct with a float, and you were adding a double value to it, the extra precision would need to be discarded each time it's assigned back to a float.

Comment: @BryceWagner: you're thinking of x87 80-bit registers.  x86-64 code always uses XMM registers (with SSE2 or AVX instructions) for scalar `double`.  `addsd`  rounds to 64-bit `double` directly.  And besides, if this was like `gcc -ffloat-store`, it wouldn't be copying the 64-bit bit-pattern with integer instructions, it would just store and reload.  If you wanted to compute in float precision, you'd use `addss`.  SSE/SSE2 being a SIMD extension (with scalar in the low element of vector regs) has to care about sizes because narrow float -> 4 elements per 128-bit vector instead of 2 `double`.

Comment: This is a long-standing issue in the jit, see eg [dotnet/coreclr#1161](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/1161). Struct wrapped doubles get passed in integer registers and the jit does not cope with this as well as one would like.